# FullScreen Flash Asset Dimensions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, fullscreen, filesize

I'm creating a media player (mostly video but with some graphical interfaces) that has a full-screen mode. However, before going fullscreen it's relatively small (about 620x340) and going fullscreen would typically be about double the resolution.

What is the best way to prepare the videos and assets in the file so they look good at fullscreen and at the smaller size? I want to also keep the file size to a minimum (within reason).

By the way, most of the graphics will be bitmaps rather than vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way, is to not scale your interface, just the video. And you should write code to set the size rather than relying on the default scaling behaviour.

Set scaleMode to no scale for your application:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Then when you switch your displayState to fullscreen, just move everything based on the screen edges.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I think I'll do.

Comment: Update, the nature of the assets i got from the designer makes this method inapplicable. The interface is going to take up the full screen and not be vector-based. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with TandemAdam's suggestion on not scaling your interface.  I'd also add that you should try turning on `smoothing` for flash.media.Video and `smoothBitmapContent` for mx.controls.Image (there are analogous properties for corresponding Flex 4 components), if you intend to scale those types of content beyond their actual resolutions.